# System Output Window message is not getting splitted into two....!

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, enterprise-architect

The issue is with the “System Output Window” in EA.
I am using EA with C# Add-in and MDG Technology, From C# Add-in I have a line to display, and that is...!

I have a message to display in the “System Output Window” on call of some event. Now I want that message to be split into two different lines, which shall display in two different lines in the System Output Window.

**
Session.Repository.WriteOutput(“”, “The content here should be split into two different lines and displayed in the system output window in two lines”, 0);
**
i also tried "\n" but it didn't help me.
“The content here should be split into two different lines \nand displayed in the system output window in two lines”(but this didn't work).
[image]

Comment: I guess, the answer is "it does not work". Send a feature request. http://sparxsystems.com/support/forms/feature_request.html

Comment: Yup, copied that. and thank you.